# Configuring an application to synchronize and retrieve MBO data

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sybase

We are following sybase online documents.
According to that doc we have imported  libraries and codes successfully.

And now to configure the application as per the document we have to register the callback first by using the following:

Register the callback object by executing:

MyCallbackHandler* theCallbackHandler = [MyCallbackHandler new];
    [SampleApp_SampleAppDB registerCallbackHandler:theCallbackhandler];

In which file should we write this code?

Answer (score 0):

This should be in application initialization time. for example ViewController.m on view did load.